# bootstrap-select stretched on safari but looks normal on chrome

Tags: bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using bootstrap-select it looks normal on chrome but on safari its stretched . heres an image attached:

[image]

not sure what could be causing it. I use bootstrap across my work and its only the boostrap-select / bootstrap-selectpicker thats doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

After inspecting the page I realised that it was being affected by the height being set at 100%.

I updated

```
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle .filter-option {
    height:100%;
}
```

to

```
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle .filter-option {
    height:auto!important;
}
```

this did not affect the dropdown on chrome at all but resolved the issue on safari